# Permutation-invariant neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, feature-selection

I have a dataset from Multiple Object Tracking trials, where a participant follows 8 points on a display, 4 of which are targets (marked briefly at the beginning of the trial) and 4 are distractors. At the end of the trial, the person marks the 4 targets. My dataset only includes trials where the participant's reply was correct. I have 10 frames per second, each frame includes the positions of the points and the position of the eye gaze, so 18 numbers in total. A trial lasts 8 seconds.
There are 40 possible trajectories for the points.

[image: An example of what a frame in a trial looks like, the red points are targets, the blue cross is the gaze.]

I'm trying to train a neural net to mark the 4 targets solely based on the positions of gaze and the points. The problem is, in the data set, the answer is always the first 4 points in the vector. If I used these outputs for training, the net would just learn to always say [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0].
Is there a way I can alter the input or output(or both) — by computing different features for example — so that it doesn't matter to the net in what order it recieved the points? The fact that a point's coordinates are the first(second, third…) in the input vector conveys no meaning in this task.

What I tried so far:

- during training, permute each input randomly (and output
  correspodningly) and iterate over all 70 possible permutations of the
  output vector [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0] so that the permutations are
  represented equally in the training. Didn't work (success rate was
  1/70, which is equal to chance)
- sort the points from left to right (by x-coordinate) - results improved, but the net basically memorized the trajectory and worked equally well even when I removed the eye gaze position. Of course I want the net to reply correctly even for new trajectories that it wasn't trained on

I have an idea for input features, I could partition the display into a discrete mesh and put 1 where there is a point, some other number where the position of the gaze is and 0 elsewhere. I don't know however, what would the output look like, any ideas?

I know I can't find an answer about a whole trial from one frame, so I'm hoping to combine the outputs of the net for all 80 frames of a trial and find the answer from that.

I'm not even sure there is any hope an NN would manage to learn this. Are there any machine-learning models that are permutation-invariant? I have searched for a long time and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PointNet](http://stanford.edu/~rqi/pointnet/) architecture. They are solving a similar problem but in 3D.

The basic approach is as follows. Feed all the points to an embedding layer which maps *x* and *y* coordinates into a higher dimensional space. These are the local features of the points. Then, feed all the local features into a "global feature extractor" module whose last layer is a max-pool. The output of this module represents the whole input and the max-pool at the end guarantees permutational invariance (or "symmetry"). Then, concatenate all the local features with the global feature and you get the complete feature set for each point. Finally, map each point's features to the point's class via a dense layer and you are done.

If you take a look at the [PointNet source code](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet), you will see that it is quite easy to implement this architecture.